# NodeJS async: Access results of forEach loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I'm using async for NodeJS and iterating over an array as follows:

```
var async = require('async')

async.forEach(myArray, function (entry, callback) {
  callback(null, entry["value"] + 1)
}, function (error, axResults_p) {
  console.log(arguments)
})
```

My problem is, that I cannot access the second parameter passed to the callback function. console.log(arguments) shows only one entry. But as far as I know, the first entry is reserved to check for errors.

So, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong/how I can access the results (entry["value"]+1)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async.map, async.parallel` instead, `each` if you want the result from the iterate function.

Comment: Ok, but it seems that I cannot pass an array to async.parallel or async.series as first parameter. It always throws an Exception: TypeError: wrapAsync(...) is not a function when I replace forEach with series or parallel.

Comment: try this 
var async = require('async')

async.map(myArray, function (entry, callback) {
  callback(null, entry["value"] + 1)
}, function (error, axResults_p) {
  console.log(arguments)
})

Comment: try `async.map`

Comment: asyc.parallel expects a list of functions as the first argument.